# Integrating AngularJS with Play framework

Tags: angularjs, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have in my javascript the following AngularJS snippet:

```
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/checklogin'
        })
       .then(function successCallback(response) {
             alert('It worked');
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
             alert('Error:' + response.status)
          });
```

That points in the `routes` file to a Play Controller:

```
POST /checklogin controllers.CheckLogin.index
```

The problem is that for **each** different Angular HTTP post I need to create an entry in `routes` (around 200 entries to create and maintain). Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic matching in routes and match your route somewhere in your application, but it isn't elegant solution.

```
GET   /*yourRoute          AppController.matcher(yourRoute)
```

Comment: This is how I made it work: using direct access to the `public` folder in Play. No need to declare routing, just point the url to the static file in the form `asset/my-file.html`.